# Notepad++: How to change Tab key to other key for auto-completion insert? Conflict with other plugin

Tags: notepad++, plugins, autocomplete, tab-key

I have installed the [FingerText](https://github.com/erinata/FingerText) plugin. It uses `Tab` key to insert snippets. But default **NP++** auto-complete also uses `Tab` and so **FingerText** is stepped on by the default - the default hint appears at first and it gets impossible for **FingerText** to insert its snippet.

How to set only `Enter` key for default hints and `Tab` key for **FingerText** hints? Now both `Enter` and `Tab` are used for default insertion. Let it be only `Enter`.

Answer (score 2):

You can change command shortcuts by going to `Settings -> Shortcut Mapper -> Plugin Commands`. Make sure `'Trigger Snippet/Navigate to Hotspot'` is the only command to which the `Tab` key is assigned.

Comment: Doesn't work. They are somehow bound. They work together. I've disabled `Tab` key for Scintilla and whichever key or combination I set for the FingerText it begins to work for default inserts too.

Comment: Are you running the latest version of FingerText? According to the changelog (https://github.com/erinata/FingerText), this issue was fixed several versions ago.