# Notepad++: disable enter key for auto-complete

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++

Is there any way to disable <kbd>enter</kbd> as auto-complete key?
I like autocomplete to be switched on for words, but there are times, when I need to new line while auto-complete is showing.

I'd like auto-complete to just trigger on <kbd>tab</kbd> for that reason. It's kinda more than average annoyance for me.

There is a similarly-looking [question](https://superuser.com/questions/564311/notepad-how-to-change-tab-key-to-other-key-for-auto-completion-insert-confli), but it is not similar.

Answer (score 6):

In Settings -> Shortcut mapper -> Scintilla commands

Double click `SCI_NEWLINE` (should be item 9 in the list), select `Enter` and remove it.

------ EDIT -------

Note that you can't add `Enter` back after removing it in Notepad++. One way to add it back is open `%appdata%\Notepad++\shortcuts.xml` file, and change following lines:

```
<ScintillaKeys>
    <ScintKey ScintID="2329" menuCmdID="0" Ctrl="no" Alt="no" Shift="yes" Key="13" />
</ScintillaKeys>
```

to following:

```
<ScintillaKeys/>
```

save file and restarte NotePad++, and the setting should be restored.

Comment: Hey! I did that and now Notepad++ does not auto-indent for me. I cannot re-add the Enter shortcut so now I'm screwed X.X Please tell me what to do.

Comment: @Foxcat385 updated my answer for how to add back Enter shortcut.

Comment: You can't use <kbd>right</kbd> because there's a conflict, but it's a different situation; so, you should be able to use <kbd>right</kbd>.

Comment: Where do you find the ScintIDs?

Answer (score 5):

In the current Notepad++ version (8.2.1) it is possible to set autocompletion keys easily in `Settings` -> `Preferences` dialog.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to disable it, but a workaround would be to hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> before <kbd>Enter</kbd> to close the suggestion pop-up in that special situation where you want to insert a new line instead of auto-completing.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [related Github issue](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/4799), there is nothing you can do in Notepad++ to prevent this. It would have to be changed in Scintilla itself.

I've resorted to an **AutoHotkey** script to replace Enter with Esc + Enter while in Notepad++:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class Notepad++
Enter::SendInput {Esc}{Enter}
```

This appears to work perfectly so far. Any menus/dialogs opened by Notepad++ have a different `ahk_class`, so this script won't send Esc+Enter when you just want to e.g. confirm a dialog with Enter.